# Wait for all promissed to resolve and/or reject?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I need array of rejection/resolution values for multiple request made in parallel. Angular `$q` do not provide such option (`$q.all` will return array of values only if every single request resolved!).

Is there Angular way for doing it, or should I look for some 3rd party promise handling library, like maybe original Q?

Comment: It's seems to me that $q.all() is designed for this purpose

Comment: @sohannohemy Not really. If any promise rejects I will only get its value. So e.g. if I make 10 requests and 6 of them fail. I will only get info why single of them failed, and no info that 5 succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Angular $q service does not provide this feature. It is, however, available in Kris Kowal's (the original) Q as `allSettled`.

Example from [the docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination):

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
            var value = result.value;
        } else {
            var reason = result.reason;
        }
    });
});
```

You could look at [the source code](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L1681) for this method and implement it in Angular your self

```
/**
 * Turns an array of promises into a promise for an array of their states (as
 * returned by `inspect`) when they have all settled.
 * @param {Array[Any*]} values an array (or promise for an array) of values (or
 * promises for values)
 * @returns {Array[State]} an array of states for the respective values.
 */
Promise.prototype.allSettled = function () {
    return this.then(function (promises) {
        return all(array_map(promises, function (promise) {
            promise = Q(promise);
            function regardless() {
                return promise.inspect();
            }
            return promise.then(regardless, regardless);
        }));
    });
};
```

But my advice would be to use the standard Q library and wrap it in an Angular service.